# Getting Hypsometric curve and Integral from elevation data in ENVI?

Tags: elevation, envi, histogram

I am attempting to get the hypsometric curve (HC) and integral (HI) from some elevation data. The data I have is in ENVI format (ENVI ROIs and DEMs). Eventually, I would like to automate this, but for now, I just want to calculate the HC and HI for a few example cases using the ENVI GUI.

This should be very simple: calculate the histogram for the ROI, divide the values of the histogram by the highest histogram value (to normalize it to 1; this will give the HC), then sum the histogram values to get the HI.

I can't seem to find anything about calculating histograms in ENVI. Could someone provide instructions (or a link) on how to use ENVI to do the process described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open DEM file and assign ROI vector (I'm using OS X version of ENVI):

[image]

In ROI window, go to `Compute Statistics from ROIs`:

[image]

A new window will appear with histogram computation:

[image]

Export text file, open it in a spreadsheet or any statiscial software and create an hipsometry curve with Relative Height ~ Relative Area:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. 
Slight addition of info for possible future readers, double clicking the ROI in the layer manager opens the ROI tool. Also, I can right click on the ROI in the layer manager and then select statistics, and that will calculate the histogram (image 3).

Comment: Do you know any way to control the bin size used in the histogram computation? ENVI seems to automatically select bin sizes based on the spread of values, but I need bin sizes of 1. Otherwise, the hypsometric curve and integral are distorted.